# Syntax Error: identifier 'Edge'?

Tags: c++, scope

At the consturctor Node = new Node[numberOfNodes]; and Edge = new Edge[numberOfEdges]; gives identifier error? what's the wrong with it ?

```
typedef struct node
{
 int id;
 int x;
 int y;
} Node;

typedef struct edge
{
 int id;
 Node node1;
 Node node2;
} Edge;

class graph
{
private:
 int numberOfNodes;
 int numberOfEdges;
 int *Node;
 int *Edge;

public:
 graph(int nodes, int edges)
 {
  numberOfNodes = nodes;
  numberOfEdges = edges;
  Node = new Node[numberOfNodes];
  Edge = new Edge[numberOfEdges];
 }
```

Comment: Why the struct typedef?  Just `struct _name_ { _members_ };` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various variable name conflicts, including a conflict between your variable declaration `int* Node`, and the typedef `Node`.  Also, you declare your array of nodes as type `int*` when it should be type `Node*`.  You do the same with `Edge`.  Try the following instead:

```
class graph
{
    private:
    int numberOfNodes;
    int numberOfEdges;
    Node* nodes_;
    Edge* edges_;

    public:

    graph(int num_nodes, int num_edges)
    {
        numberOfNodes = num_nodes;
        numberOfEdges = num_edges;
        nodes_ = new Node[numberOfNodes];
        edges_ = new Edge[numberOfEdges];
    }
};
```

Also, just for the future, the `typedef struct { }` idiom is really unnecessary in C++.  It's main purpose was so that C programmers wouldn't need to constantly have to prefix their struct variables with the word `struct`.  But in C++ this isn't necessary, so there's generally no real reason to say `typedef struct node { ... } Node;` when you can just say `struct Node { ... };`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, `Node` and `Edge` refer to the `int*` members of the class, *not* the type names in the global scope. You will have to indicate that you're referring to the global types:

```
Node = new ::Node[numberOfNodes];
Edge = new ::Edge[numberOfEdges];
```

**Edit:** of course, this would still confuse human readers. It's advised to keep type and variable names separate for the sake of your readers.

Comment: This would work.  But really, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is confused by the fact that you used `Node` and `Edge` both as a type identifier (in `typedef ... Node;`) and as a class member (`int *Node`).  I was confused for a while too.  You can't really do that.  In general, it's a good idea to choose different names for types, members, and variables that are supposed to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I've written nonsense things..it was like that. However I get still erors:
Eerror C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Edge *' to 'int'

```
public:
    graph(int nodes, int edges)
    {
        numberOfNodes = nodes;
        numberOfEdges = edges;
        nodes = new Node[numberOfNodes];
        edges = new Edge[numberOfEdges];
    }
```

Comment: I've seen my mistake. Thanks for all answers.